# Как закомпилить код в linux при помощи g++?

Tags: c++, linux, компиляция, g++

Пытаюсь скомпилировать С++ код компилятором g++ в ubuntu.
Код:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<chrono>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     return 0;
}
```

Как компилирую:

```
g++ -c lab2.cc
g++ -o lab2 lab2.o
```

Вывод:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/chrono:35:0,
from lab2.cc:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++ox_warning.h:32:2: ошибка #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++ox or -str=gnu++ox compiler options.

Comment: Ну дайте вы ему ключи, которые он просит. Или выкиньте лишние заголовочные файлы...

Comment: @Harry какие ключи ему нужно передать? Я не шарю просто

Comment: Напишите cmake файл. После него вам достаточно будет написать cmake и make

Comment: Я думаю *chrono* лишний. И *thread* скорее всего туда же. А вообще компилятор лучше посвежее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно дописать `-std=c++11` -  это заставит компилятор использовать свежий стандарт.

Comment: не распознает такую опцию

Comment: Ну, есть вероятность, что у вас старенький компилятор. Об этом можно узнать g++ -v

Comment: @ДенисГудойть Обновляйте компилятор. Когда я лет пять назад начинал С/С++ изучать, у меня и то новее гцц был.